# Why am I getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I'm trying to assign an instance of a Form to a Form Property

The system keeps showing an error at my second line of code below

```
Dim objFrm = New LsProg.SFile.frmTestRel(AddressOf sOpDos, AddressOf sOpDosLine, AddressOf sOpFac) 
_FavoriteForm.FrmInstance = objFrm
_FavoriteForm.FrmName = objFrm.Name
```

Comment: What is `_FavoriteForm` and how is it initialised?

Comment: I would assume that _FavoriteForm is not initialized before this code is ran.

Comment: _FavoriteForm is a class with 2 properties (name of type string and instance of type Form)

Comment: `_FavoriteForm` appears to also be `Null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `NullReferenceException` you need to think about what is actually `Null` and then go back and make sure you initialise it.

You told us

```
_FavoriteForm.FrmInstance = objFrm
```

threw this exception, so `_FavoriteForm` is clearly `Null` and needs to be initialised fist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize _FavoriteForm before running this code.